# How to extend and hide tags?

Tags: flutter

I want to achieve this:

[image]

This are tags with possibility to expand and hide them, like with this package: https://pub.dev/packages/readmore,

but `readmore` is working with text and my tags are not text.

Here is what my code look like:

```
Wrap(
                          children: [
                            for (var item in partyMap['tags'])
                              Container(
                                height: size.height * 0.03,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: size.width * 0.02,
                                    vertical: size.height * 0.0035
                                ),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    right: size.width * 0.01,
                                    bottom: size.height * 0.007
                                ),
                                child: Text(
                                  item['name'].toString()
                                ),
                              ),
                          ],
                        ),
```

My question is there a package to do what I want or maybe some workaround with `readmore` or other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use animated container to expand and shrink.

```
class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: const Center(
          child: MoreContainer(child: TagsView()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TagsView extends StatelessWidget {
  const TagsView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      runSpacing: 2,
      spacing: 2,
      children:
          List.generate(20, (index) => InputChip(label: Text('Tag-$index'))),
    );
  }
}

class MoreContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  const MoreContainer({super.key, required this.child});
  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<MoreContainer> createState() => _MoreContainerState();
}

class _MoreContainerState extends State<MoreContainer> {
  // Define the various properties with default values. Update these properties
  // when the user taps a FloatingActionButton.
  final double _minHeight = 80;
  double _height = 80;
  bool isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        AnimatedContainer(
          height: _height,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(),

          // Define how long the animation should take.
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          // Provide an optional curve to make the animation feel smoother.
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          child: widget.child,
        ),
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  isExpanded ? _height = _minHeight : _height = 250;
                  isExpanded = !isExpanded;
                }),
            child: Text(isExpanded ? 'Show less' : 'Show more'))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is really helpful, but I have one more question, how to achieve that opacity visible on provided screen when tags are hidden?

Comment: The answer above is not the best solution as I didn't use dynamic height or colors. You can achieve fading effect by using a stack and container with a gradient.